# Arrumar permissões na raiz do linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, permissões

Fiz uma besteira aqui no meu linux, executei isso:

```
sudo chown -Rf www-data.www-data /*
```

E dei um `ctrl+c` depois de 4 segundos... porque vi a burrada que tinha feito.

Era pra ser isso:

```
sudo chown -Rf www-data.www-data ./*
```

E agora está dando erro no sudo su, como corrigir isso?

```
 /etc/sudoers tem como dono o uid 33, deveria ser 0
```

Comment: em qual diretorio vc estava qundo executou este comando? se voce executou esse comando na raiz acho melhor reinstalar o sistema

Comment: nao importa o diretorio que ele executou, ao colocar somente a barra automaticamente o comando foi executado na raiz

Comment: Vou ter que reinstalar, mas obrigado pela ajuda...

Answer (score 2):

Você pode entrar como super usuário com o comando `su`, ao contrario do `sudo`, o `su` efetua a autenticação como super usuário (Necessário a senha de super usuário e não a de usuário).

Ou efetue o login direto como super usuário. ***"Inicie o modo terminal e logue como root"***.

Apos um desses passos, rode o comando:

```
$ chown -Rf root:root /bin/ /usr/ /dev /boot /etc /lib* /mnt /opt /proc /root /sys
```

A pasta `home` não está entre elas para não dar problemas com o usuário.

Isso vai restaurar a permissão da maioria dos arquivos, na pasta ***var***, algumas pastas possuem usuários e grupos diferentes de ***root***, se for restaurar o diretório ***/var*** tome cuidado quanto a isso.

> Logar diretamente como super usuário pelo modo terminal é o mais recomendado.

Comment: Tentei isso mas não deu certo, infelizmente. Mesmo passando os donos para estes diretórios ainda não consegui logar no sistema...

Comment: Qual é a sua distribuição? Lembra da senha do root? (como você usa o sudo, pode ser que use apenas a senha de usuário e não lembre da senha do root).

Comment: É o ubuntu linux 14.04 LTS, lembro a senha sim, inclusive já até entrei em modo de recuperação, como root e digitei lá "passwrd ivan" e também "passwrd root", resetei as senhas, e mesmo assim, não entra... meu usuário era "/home/ivan", até tentei jogar o meu usuário para ser o dono, `chown ivan:ivan -Rf /home/ivan` e nada...

Comment: só consigo entrar na tela de "convidado".

Comment: tentou digitar aquele o comando no modo de recuperação? tente usar um cd live

Comment: Consegui resolver, instalei o ubuntu de novo, o problema é que como disse um colega, existem "n" arquivos com "n" permissões, e cada uma tem uma permissão para um determinado processo, para você corrigir tudo, você levaria dias, para revistar e saber o que cada arquivo do sistema faz, e quem tem as permissões, você até poderia conseguir, mas iria ter que se dedicar por bastante tempo. Por isso, a melhor coisa a fazer é formatar. Em suma: eu não iria conseguir.

Comment: Mas obrigado pela resposta.